# I'm looking to install linux on a lenovo with 64-bit core and 32-bit UEFI

Tags: linux

I'm looking to install *Linux* on a **Lenovo Thinkpad 100s**, which has a `64-bit core` and a `32-bit UEFI`. This is a problem for Linux flash installers, which seem to require a patch/compile to make this work with a 64-bit build.

Is 64-bit necessary? Considering that there is only 2GB available memory - it seems unnecessary to go through the trouble of compiling a loader with GRUB2, at least when the 64-bit addressing wouldn't be able to utilize the extra addressing. (Note: I saw note somewhere that some of the Ubuntu builds are pre-patched for this, but I haven't tried it yet tonight).

I haven't checked the 32-bit installs yet, so I don't know if those would work. It seems like the 64-bit chip is just a currently cheaper (and energy-efficient) alternative that wouldn't really play into performance with only 2GB available, but maybe I'm missing something.

What would be the advantage of `64` over `32-bit` addressing in this case? Should I just save myself the 2 hours of smacking my head trying to get this thing to work, or is there some advantage to a 64-bit core that I haven't seen yet?

Comment: Couldn't you just turn off Secure Boot or set it for Legacy or Other OS? And the biggest problem will be 32-bit support, many distros have dropped it completely, many more will soon, as have many applications.

Comment: You'd think so, but for whatever reason - while the chip itself is 64-bit, the UEFI is 32-bit and won't recognize the bootloader at all, meaning it won't show up in the BIOS, even with secure boot off.
Also: It seems odd to me that it would make a difference between 32/64 bit versions when there isn't even enough memory available to take advantage of the extra addressing.

Answer (score -1):

This would really come down to what are you doing with the computer. While a lot of it (64 bit / 32 bit) is similar. It only refers to the way the ram is handled. With little ram 32 bit is fine. Issue with some 32 bit is that some things such as chrome is no longer supported in 3w bit but there are alternatives to almost all these issues.